# I want to make my popup div fixed to the place

Tags: html, css, popup

I have a popup on my page, it display on clicking any div on the page.
There are multiple divs, with which this popup is associated.
Now the issue is if i click on div, popup gets open, but if i scroll, popup also scroll and come to wrong div.
How to make it fixed to its associated div after click?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Need more information that current post, enter all details like screen shots and code which not working and error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example. I'm hoping this is something like what you're talking about. When the first box is clicked, an alert pops up and stays with the first box when scrolling.

I used simple jQuery to create the popup.

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.alert').css('display', 'block');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d8xwev9o/

Comment: Thank You Adam, it worked for me after making css changes related to position.